# Показ подсказок при выделенни чекбоксов

Tags: javascript, checkbox

Есть несколько чекбоксов. Когда выделяется чекбокс, возле него появляется подсказка. Проблема в том, что выделить можно только 1 чекбокс. Как сделать, чтобы была возможность выделять больше одного?

```js
$(".shop__check input[type='checkbox']").click(function() {
    $(".cat__count").hide();
    $(".shop__check input[type='checkbox']").not(this).each(function() {
        this.checked = false;
    });
    if (this.checked) $("." + $(this).data("blockclass")).show();
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    $(".shop__check input[type='checkbox']").not(this).each(function() {
      $("." + $(this).data("blockclass")).toggle(this.checked);
    });
```

Comment: Спасибо, помогло

Comment: @barmaley Пожалуйста. Знак "галочка" - слева от ответа.

Comment: еще рано, сайт говорит через 5 минут